# How to fractionalize ownership of a collection of NFTs across multiple investors?

Tags: blockchain, wallets, erc-721, nft

An Ether wallet contains a large collection of ERC-721 NFTs. Normally only one owner knows the seed phrase for a wallet and therefore is the owner of all the NFTs inside the wallet.

How can such a wallet's digital assets be fractionalized amongst multiple owners instead so that new money facilitates further acquisitions? Is there a smart contract wizard/app that allows the genesis owner to distribute shares of ownership across multiple incoming investors? The idea is to attract and convince investors that their fractional ownership is guaranteed and immutable on the blockchain.

A conceptual schematic map of how this works economically and mechanically, maybe in the form of a numbered list, might be good enough.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a DAO which can buy the NFTs and then you can fractionalize ownership of the DAO however you want.

This notably happened to purchase this NFT:

https://www.theblockcrypto.com/post/99615/uniswap-v3-nft-sold-dao-half-million-dollars

Comment: ***how* does somebody create a DAO**? these one sentence answers that provide none of the steps asked for is exactly what i was trying to avoid

Comment: If you're a programmer, watch this tutorial to understand how fractionalization is implemented in solidity https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9CBDj5A-zz4 If you're not a programmer, but have hired one, get them to watch it.

Comment: could u summarize that video with a brief instruction as a separate answer